# How can I execute a Python entry_point script with a windows batch file?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file

I've a Python package providing a CLI and GUI via `setup.py` `entry_point` `console scripts` (resulting in `cli.exe` and `gui.exe` on Windows). I'd like to provide a simple "desktop icon" to Windows users via a batch file placed on the desktop. As the setup is static it's not a problem to define absolute the paths (both do not contain whitespaces or utf-8 incompatible chars) in the batch file `gui.bat` like:

```
C:\\Some\\Path\\to\\Python36\\python.exe C:\\Another\\Path\\to\\gui.exe
pause
```

The `gui.bat` is UTF-8 encoded and the path to Python (`>where Python`) and the executable (`>where gui.exe`) are correct. If I execute the batch file I get

```
File "C:\\Another\\Path\\to\\gui.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\\Another\\Path\\to on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

for the first executed batch file line. I've defined all `.py` files to be utf-8 encoded via `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line (missing Unix shebang line should not make any difference). What's going wrong?

Comment: hi, 
1. usually batch files does not required double back-slashes when referring to paths. can you look into this command as well "chcp" to set code-page.
2. may be try adding this as first line as well 
#!c:/Python36/python.exe

Comment: @NizamudeenA I got an error that `#!c:` is missspelled or could not be found. Could you explain in more detail pls.